# Spring Security- Allows GET but not POST

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building a simple application and I am new to Spring Security so please bear with me. But anyway I have a RESTful application that takes some info and displays the info into a table. Before implementing spring security everything worked fine. But now I am only able to login to the app and not use the rest of the functionality. The AJAX initially gets all of my info for my table and that works fine but when I go to post data to my database it returns a 403 FORBIDDEN.

Here is my security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <cors />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/TAS/students" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <form-login />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService"/> 
</authentication-manager>   

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my Spring config servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation=
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

 <annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


  <beans:bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="prefix">
      <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</beans:value>
   </beans:property>
   <beans:property name="suffix">
      <beans:value>.jsp</beans:value>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tds_mock" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="blahblah" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="blahblah" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
 <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
  <beans:list>
<beans:value>tas.web.student.Student</beans:value>
<beans:value>tas.web.user.User</beans:value>
<beans:value>tas.web.user.UserRole</beans:value>
</beans:list>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
   <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="userDao" class="tas.web.user.UserDAOImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" 
ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="myUserDetailService" class="tas.web.user.UserService">
    <beans:property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>


  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 <beans:bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory" 
ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
  </beans:bean> 


   <context:component-scan base-package="tas.web"/>

</beans:beans>
```

And Finally here is my restcontroller

```
package tas.web.student;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tas.web.student.StudentService;
import net.aksingh.owmjapis.CurrentWeather;
import net.aksingh.owmjapis.OpenWeatherMap;


@RestController
public class StudentController {

 @Autowired
 StudentService studentService;

 @GetMapping(value = "/students")
 public List<Student> getStudents() {

  List<Student> listOfStudents = studentService.getStudents();
  return listOfStudent;
 }

 @GetMapping(value = "/students/{studentID}")
 public Student getStudentById(@PathVariable long studentID) {
  return studentService.getStudent(studentID);
 }

 @PostMapping(value = "/students")
 public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) { 
  return studentService.addStudent(student);
 }

 @PutMapping(value = "/students/{studentID}")
 public Student updateStudent(@PathVariable("studentID") Long studentID, @RequestBody Student student) {
  return studentService.updateStudent(student);
 }

 @DeleteMapping(value = "/students/{studentID}")
 public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable("studentID") long studentID) {
  studentService.deleteStudent(studentID);  
 } 

 @GetMapping(value = "/current/{city}")
 public ResponseEntity currentWeather(@PathVariable("city") String city) throws IOException{
    OpenWeatherMap openWMap = new OpenWeatherMap("APIkey");
    CurrentWeather currentW = openWMap.currentWeatherByCityName(city);      
    return new ResponseEntity(currentW, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

My database is MySQL 5.7.3 and I am using hibernate to access it. Everything worked fine until I implemented the spring security. If any other files are needed please let me know and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your *.jsp's with a 'post' form in it add this taglib to the top of your file:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" 
  prefix ="security" %>
```

Then in the head section of the jsp add this:

```
<security:csrfMetaTags />
```

And in the form tag add this:

```
<security:csrfInput/>
```

You must also have the following dependency in your build:

> org.springframework.security
>        spring-security-taglibs

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is simply doing it job.

What you should know

Spring security guides against Cross Site Request Forgery attack (CSRF attack) and this feature is enabled by default.
So now that you have implemented spring security, you need to pass CSRF token in all your form post and ajax post request for those request to be executed successfully otherwise spring security will throw an AccessDeniedException and return error 403 as response.

Read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) Spring security doc for a better understanding of the usefulness of Spring security CSRF feature and how to work with it.

Comment: So say just for the sake of getting the application to continue to work before diving in head first and really nailing this down, I disabled the csrf and I still get the same errors. Is there some other aspect that I am not understanding? @Perry